# Pandas : Create multiple new variables by applying function to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following simple function:

```
def Powers(x):
    return [x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5]
```

and input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) })
```

I would like to generate new variables: `['Exp_1', 'Exp_2', 'Exp_3', 'Exp_4', 'Exp_5']`

When I apply the function to the dataframe as follows:

```
df[['Exp_1', 'Exp_2', 'Exp_3', 'Exp_4', 'Exp_5']] = df.apply(lambda x: Powers(x.x), axis=1)
```

I get:

[image]

In other words, the values are transposed.  That is, the 5th exponent of 1 is 1 not 5 and the 1st exponent of 5 is 5 and not 1.

I have tried `axis=0`, in the call above and this does not work either.  I also know I have a problem because if the input dataframe is of a different length I get errors.

How do I fix this?

Comment: not sure if `Powers` is only an example or not but for some speed if you care about it, you can go for `np.vander(df.x, len(df) + 1, increasing=True)`; this generates a Vandermonde matrix https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html.

Comment: Thanks.  Powers is just a trivial example for MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return Series in `Powers` function

```py
def Powers(x):
    return pd.Series([x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5])

df[['Exp_1', 'Exp_2', 'Exp_3', 'Exp_4', 'Exp_5']] = df.apply(lambda x: Powers(x.x), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   x  Exp_1  Exp_2  Exp_3  Exp_4  Exp_5
0  1      1      1      1      1      1
1  2      2      4      8     16     32
2  3      3      9     27     81    243
3  4      4     16     64    256   1024
4  5      5     25    125    625   3125
```

Or use `result_type` in `DataFrame.apply`

```py
def Powers(x):
    return [x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5]

df[['Exp_1', 'Exp_2', 'Exp_3', 'Exp_4', 'Exp_5']] = df.apply(lambda x: Powers(x.x), axis=1, result_type='expand')
# or
df[['Exp_1', 'Exp_2', 'Exp_3', 'Exp_4', 'Exp_5']] = df.apply(lambda x: Powers(x.x), axis=1).tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  I will experiment with both, but let's say the function will sometimes be used with a scalar and sometimes applied to a dataframe, is option 2 preferred?

Comment: @brb Don't quite know what you mean *applied to a dataframe*. If you mean what you do in this example, it's actually same with `df['x'].apply(Powers)`. Both ways are ok, depending on which you like.

Comment: Sorry, I mean sometimes I might want to do results = Powers(3) and before results would be a list.  I am not sure I want to return a pd.Series in this case.  So your second way of doing result_type='Expand' maybe better as it can be used with a scalar input or used by applying to a dataframe?

Comment: @brb In your `results = Powers(3)`, I think second way is better.

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciate your help.  Helping me learn.